# Common UI code in a base class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a scenario where I need to put some common code into a base class (proposed solution).

Say I have the below code inside a UserControl class file BookingsCreatePage.cs

```
public partial class BookingsCreatePage : UserControl, IPrototypeUX
{
    public BookingsCreatePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupPadding();
    }

    //Implementing my own Interface IPrototypeUX here
    void SetupPadding()
    {
        tlpBase.Margin = new Padding(0);

        panelHeading.Margin = new Padding(0);
        tlpBookingDetails.Margin = new Padding(7, 0, 7, 0);
        panelNav.Margin = new Padding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        panelWarning.Margin = new Padding(0);
    }
}
```

Now I want to put `panelNav.Margin = new Padding(10, 0, 10, 0);` line into a common area, possibly a base class or something which I cannot think right now.

I'm having same named panel in each of my UserControls. So either I need to pass this `panelNav` variable to the base class as a parameter or somehow hardcode it there.

What would be the best way to do this common coding structure?

Answer (score 0):

How about having you own base custom UserControl which inherits from UserControl. Something like below,

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
```

You can move the common logic of specifying the margin for the controls panel there and even specify some prerequisites in `MyUserControl` and use that in your Forms or Controls. Your scenario would then look like,

```
public partial class BookingsCreatePage : MyUserControl, IPrototypeUX
```

This way you will have control and not have to keep doing the same in all cases where the control is used.

Comment: Well. It seems my situation would be better solved by a simple static class member where I can put some common code.